# ssmtp, mailutils and GMail how to set username?

Tags: gmail, ssmtp, mailutils

Ubuntu 18.04, ssmtp installed, mailutils installed and everything works, can send through gmail.  My problem is that the messages when received appear to be from "Root (my-real-email@gmail.com)" I am trying to change "root" to a name that wont set off my spam filters at work, which "root" seems to do.

How do I set the username so it appears in the outgoing message as something other than "Root"?

Comment: It would be easier, and you would be using a better application, if you used msmtp. Then you would simply set a 'From:' field in a local `~/.msmtprc` file...

Comment: Sorry, I have multiple deployments of ssmtp, not changing unless forced to do so.  Ssmtp allows setting from *address* but I can't figure how to set username

Comment: Fair enough. If you have a look at the base of the ssmtp man pages you will see a section called 'Reverse Aliases'. I quote that section: 'A reverse alias gives the From: address placed on a user's outgoing messages and (optionally) the mailhub these messages will be sent through'. Which I believe is what you are after? Should be placed in `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases`. Untested by me but if this does not work I will install ssmtp and test it all out...

Comment: Setting the "from" value changes the address, not the username.  A message sent from ssmtp will appear as being sent by username(email@somewhere.com) where the from address is email@somewhere.com.  Username is what I am trying to change, it apparently defaults to the account under which the mail command was run.  This is what I am trying to change.  All my scripts appear on sent messages as coming from "Root(someone@somewhere.com)"....and I am trying to change the "Root" part.